# How do I show the improper integral exist?

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Let $a_0=0$, and define for $k \geq 1$ $a_k=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{k}}$

Assume further that $b_k$ is sequence of positive real numbers such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_k^2 < \infty$, and that $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous and positive functions so that $f(x) \leq b_k$ when $a_{k-1} \leq |x| \leq a_k$ for $k=1,2,3,\ldots$. Show that the improper integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x) \, dx $ exists.

Can anyone give some direction to solve this question?

Comment: Notation is not clear... is $f$ defined on the plane ${\mathbb R}^2$? When you wrote $a_{k-1}\leq |x|\leq a_k$, is $x$ a real variable, or a 2-vector?

Comment: I think you meant to write $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ instead of $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$. If that was deliberate, then the condition $f(\textbf{x})\leq b_k$ doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4):

We have
$$
\iint_{a_{k-1}\leq |x|\leq a_k} f \leq b_k (\pi a_k^2-\pi a_{k-1}^2)=\frac{\pi b_k}{k},
$$
so apply the Cauchy-Shwartz inequality,
$$
\iint_{{\mathbb R}^2} f \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \iint_{a_{k-1}\leq |x|\leq a_k} f
\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\pi b_k}{k}\leq \pi \Big(\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k^2\Big)^{1/2}
\Big(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}\Big)^{1/2}<\infty. 
$$